# Mount EFS in Region Sydney to EC2 instance in Singapore region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I have created an Amazon EFS filesystem in the Sydney Region and would like to mount it on an EC2 instance in the Singapore region.

Is this possible?

Comment: Excellent question, should probably be migrated to serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This answer is outdated. Please see other answer.**

An Amazon EFS filesystem is only accessible in the VPC that was selected when it was created, or [via Direct Connect when linked to that VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-efs-update-on-premises-access-via-direct-connect-vpc/).

Each Amazon VPC is only in one Region.

As per the [Amazon EFS Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/limits.html) documentation page:

> An Amazon EFS file system **can be mounted from on-premises datacenter servers using AWS Direct Connect**. However, other VPC private connectivity mechanisms such as a VPN connection and **VPC peering are not supported**.

Comment: I wonder whether VPC peering allow such level of data sharing.

Comment: Thanks John Rotenstein,

Comment: I want to mount media folder of magento in to multi ec2 instance, Amazon S3 service is the best choice for me?

Comment: Please create a new Question rather than asking here in the Comments.

Comment: Hi @dat.tran, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid now:  Amazon EFS now Supports AWS VPN and Inter-Region VPC Peering   : https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/amazon-efs-now-supports-aws-vpn-and-inter-region-vpc-peering/

Answer (score 1):

Answering as people may not look at the comment.

You can now connect to Amazon EFS file systems from EC2 instances in other AWS regions using an inter-region VPC peering connection, and from on-premises servers using an AWS VPN connection.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/amazon-efs-now-supports-aws-vpn-and-inter-region-vpc-peering/